# Mysql union multiple tables into one large table

Tags: mysql, union

I have a query that selects the names of multiple tables:

SELECT TABLE_NAME AS TABLES FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES

```
+---------------+
| TABLES        |
+---------------+
| A             |
| B             |
| <more tables> |
+---------------+
```

I'd like to create a query where every value in each table are unioned together as such:

```
+------------+----+----------+
| table_name | id | name     |
+------------+----+----------+
| A          | 1  | item1    | <- Items from Table A
| A          | 2  | item2    | 
| A          | 3  | item3    |
| B          | 1  | item1    | <- Items from Table B
| B          | 2  | item2    |
| <entries for other tables> |
+------------+----+----------+
```

Any Ideas? Thank you in advance!

Comment: That doesn't sound like an aggregate (`COUNT(),MAX(),MIN(),SUM(),etc`), but rather like a `UNION ALL` and an `ORDER BY table_name`.

Comment: Sorry I changed the title and the tag to be merge as opposed to aggregate. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you're employing "aggregate" in its loosest sense...

```
select 'A' as table_name, id, name
from table_a
union all
select 'B' as table_name, id, name
from table_b
```

Comment: This is on the right track! I'm curious how do I do a union for a couple hundred tables. Thanks for the speedy response.

Comment: With lots of lines. Unless these tables are tiny, this is going to be a slow query. It sounds like your database design is bad.. - needing to access schema details and union many tables points to issues in my view.

Comment: The wages of a bad data model is typing, and lots of it.

Comment: The tables are very small and come from a group of wordpress sites. I think some sort of loop over the table names would be necessary but I have never constructed a mysql loop statement to union the tables.